# Hatoras Nedarim - mentioning specific examples

Tags: halacha, rosh-hashanah-new-year, nedarim-shevuot

If one is aware of specific examples of vows or a 'minhag tov' that one undertook, then one should articulate this to at least one member of the 'judges'. Is this informing essential or does the hatoras nedarim still effectively annul these even though you decided not to articulate them to anyone?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97077/13791 very close...